# Problem with boot entry of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, bios

**Hello** I was having Ubuntu 20.04 with dualboot configuration and I decided to remove Ubuntu. So I deleted its partition and tried to path the boot file of windows from grub and also tried repairing MBR using software tool but my laptop was booting into grub. So I deleted the boot entries of Ubuntu from bios and all the things were good to go. But I yesterday just booted in the bios to check wether all the things are OK and then I found that the boot order was like this

```
Boot Order:-
1) Windows (some sort of number)
2) Windows (the same number as above)
3) Ubuntu (the same number)
4) Empty
```

I know that I deleted the boot entries of Ubuntu from bios but somehow its there again. It is not causing any problem but I am worried about it and deleted it. So what should I do to permanently delete it ? Thankyou.

Update :- I removed the dir named Ubuntu from the efi partition successfully by using cmd, so is the issue fixed ?

Update:-
Output of command `bcdedit /enum firmware`:

```
Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bootmgr}
                        {9ab9a677-88d6-11eb-8edd-806e6f6e6963}
                        {1b051e8f-99db-11eb-8ee9-806e6f6e6963}
                        {1b051e90-99db-11eb-8ee9-806e6f6e6963}
timeout                 0

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \efi\microsoft\boot
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {d728b7f0-698d-11eb-9830-f298495471f2}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {1b051e8f-99db-11eb-8ee9-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi
description             ubuntu

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {1b051e90-99db-11eb-8ee9-806e6f6e6963}
description             CD/DVD Drive

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {9ab9a677-88d6-11eb-8edd-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
```

I can see here `Ubuntu` but I followed and checked for the file after removing it, steps followed:

1. `cmd` as admin
2. `diskpart`
3. `list disk`
4. `select disk 0` (I have only single disk)
5. `sel vol 4` (It was in FAT32 file system)
6. `assign letter=R:`
7. exit
8. `cd /d R:`
9. `cd EFI`
10. `dir EFI`
11. `rmdir /s ubuntu`
12. `Y`
13. `dir EFI` (To confirm that is Ubuntu is removed and it was not there)

I can see ubuntu again here:- Image after deleting it.
[image]

This is the image after deleting ubuntu boot option by using the option present in the image but it again automattically gets added at third position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So what should I do to permanently delete it?**

[Use `bcdedit`](https://superuser.com/questions/465047/how-to-remove-an-old-os-from-the-boot-menu).

**Is the issue fixed?**

Most likely. And even if you didn't successfully remove the entry, you may consider the issue "fixed".

To answer completely your question, one would need to know exactly which commands you used and configuration actions you took, and in which order (including possible reboots).

I assume you did something like [this](https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/115716-uefi-remove-unwanted-boot-entries-bios-solved-easily-post1433082.html#post1433082).
[This](https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/iss/proliant_uefi/UEFI_Gen9_121417/s_deleting_boot_option.html) would also have been an option.

With the limited amount of information you gave, you should be good.
You could post more information to be completely sure.
For instance:

1. A screen capture of the partition scheme you get with the Win disk manager. E.g., as [under *Simplified EFI Boot Flow*](http://www.agcross.com/2017/11/making-sense-efi-partitions-dual-booting/).
2. The output of:

   2.1. `bcdedit /enum firmware` (command issued in an admin prompt).

   2.2. Commands illustrated [under *Mount the EFI partition*](http://www.agcross.com/2017/11/making-sense-efi-partitions-dual-booting/) (up to `list partition`). **Note**: If you keep reading this section, and also *Use An Alternate File System Explorer*, you will find that if you don't see the Ubuntu entry with `dir` it may not mean it's not there.
3. Exactly which commands you used to "delete the boot entries of Ubuntu from bios". The "canonical" way is [with `bcedit`](https://superuser.com/questions/465047/how-to-remove-an-old-os-from-the-boot-menu).

**Related**:

1. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_system_partition
2. http://www.agcross.com/2017/11/making-sense-efi-partitions-dual-booting/

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I have updated my answer.  @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio

Comment: Are you asking about ```cmd as admin``` ? Sorry its not a command I meant to say that I ran Command Promt as an administrator In Windows and to access partitions used ```diskpart``` utility. @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio

Comment: No bro let it be there. I appreciate for the help you did for me. @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio

Comment: I cannot see ubuntu anywhere in the output of command ```bcdedit``` so is the problem fixed ? Means if I want to do any OS operations or any other OS, will I get to see grub causing error there ?Also I removed the boot entry directly booting in my bios just by selecting the delete boot entry option and then selected ubuntu from there. I wll chech my bios soon and update you. Thankyou. @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio

Comment: Please see the updated question @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio